# python how to get button name from database

Tags: python, tkinter

hello stack overflow members 
my question is 
how i can get the Button names when the buttons are automatically generating from a database 
 like this

```
for index, dat in enumerate(data2):
        ttk.Button(master, text=dat[0]).grid(row=index+1, column=1,pady=0,padx=0)
```

any help<3

Comment: store the buttons in a dictionary if you want to give them names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or do you just want to know which button was pressed? Then try this:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

master = Tk()
data2 = ['Orange','Apple','Banana','Kiwi']
button_dict = {}

def callback_function(x): print('Pressed:', x)

for index, dat in enumerate(data2):
    button = ttk.Button(master, text=dat[0],
                        command=lambda dat=dat: callback_function(dat))
    button.grid(row=index+1, column=1,pady=0,padx=0)
    button_dict[dat] = button   # Stores a reference to the button under 
                                # the name from the database

for name in data2:
    print(name, button_dict[name])  # prints all button/name associations

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks figbeams  its so helpfull   but i need to get the name of that pressed button

Comment: With "name", do you mean **reference** so you can address the button?

Comment: Added an example of storing buttons and names in a dict.

Comment: yes bro  i want to create a simple cafe ms  so i want to save the button name and its price from a database into TextBox   please if you can help  let me share with you my code